# My source-mapped breakpoints aren't working correctly in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, google-closure-compiler, source-maps

I have created a  concatenated, minified file through the [Node.js wrapper for Google Closure Compiler](https://npmjs.org/package/closurecompiler). When I open the Developer Tools in Google Chrome, both the source map and the mapped files all load appropriately.

A problem I'm having is that breakpoints aren't triggering in the source map files like they would running an unminified, separate-file session. Sometimes I'll try to place a breakpoint in a script and it will jump several lines down rather than where I'm trying to set it. But what is most frustrating is that when I can set a breakpoint, they aren't triggered! I'll set one in the middle of a function that I *know* is being called, but the script never pauses execution.

**EDIT**

I'm running Chrome 31.0.1650.57 on Ubuntu 13.10. I can't get it to work in Firefox 25.0 either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can gather, the breakpoints jump due to the closure compiler combining statements and Chrome only supporting whole statements as breakpoints.

Comment: By "combining statements" do you mean removing newlines?

Comment: That and more, notice the output from [compiling the default](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) adapted: `
function hello(name) {
  if(name){
    alert('Hello, ' + name);
  }else{
    alert('Shy?');
  }
}
hello('New user');
`

Comment: Surprisingly, minified sources don't have the best support in Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327092