# Cannot set breakpoints at some lines in Chrome devTools source panel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app

This happens recently in my Chrome's source panel. It used to work just fine. Not sure if that's causing by the recent update of Chrome (I'm currently using 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6)

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, these are all the locations that I can set breakpoints in this file. Normally, you can at least set breakpoints at line 6-10 but now, I can only set at line 8. Why?

Anyone who is also experiencing this?

**Update**: This also happens on my Windows machine with the same 68.0.3440.106 Build.

Comment: A temp workaround for this is to use `debugger` statement in your source code. It works as expected but just not that easy to change and move around. And you have to remember to remove it from your source code when shipping to prod env.

Comment: Could it be source maps getting out of sync? See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278193/chrome-devtools-wont-let-me-set-breakpoints-on-certain-lines)