# Browser DevTools won't let me set breakpoints on certain lines even after I cleaned cache and reopen

Tags: angular, debugging, compilation, breakpoints, devtools

I have an angular project:

- angular version is 9.x
- Typescript version is  3.8.x

I can set breakpoint in every lines when I run in `ng serve`

But I can't set breakpoint in some lines when I run in `ng build`

This is is my compile options:

```
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
```

This is my related code:

```
    static httpHandle(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
            let errorMessage = '';
            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                // client-side error
                errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
            } else {
                // server-side error
                errorMessage = `Error Status: ${error.status} -- Message: ${error.message}`;
                if (error.status === 404){
                    errorMessage = "API is not found, Please contact Admin";
                }else if (error.status === 400){
                    errorMessage = error.error;
                }else if (error.status === 403){
                    errorMessage = `You don't have permission to do this`;
                }else if (error.status === 401){
                    errorMessage = `Session timeout, Please relogin`;
                }else{
                    errorMessage = `API Error: ${error.status} ${error.statusText}`;
                }
            }
            console.log(errorMessage);
            return throwError(errorMessage);
    }
```

In compiled code, only 3 lines can set breakpoint, In `ng serve`, all non-grey line can set breakpoint

I saw somebody mentioned to reopen devTools and clean cache
[Chrome DevTools won't let me set breakpoints on certain lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278193/chrome-devtools-wont-let-me-set-breakpoints-on-certain-lines)
I tried , still has the issue.

I also tried both Chrome and Edge, they have exact the same issue.

Comment: You could try using the keywork `debugger` wherever you need a break point. This way you don't need to manually put it in the browser and it will automatically stop wherever you put it.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Tried debugger; but still can't set breakpoint, also I can't step in those code lines, looks like they are not there, But the function is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can debug on all code lines after I changed `optimization`  to false, but the generated file 8 times bigger

Comment: Where is this "optimization" setting?